Clerk: Next.js SignOutButton SignOutOptions, not working
I'm trying to make my user go back to /sign-in after he clicked on the button to logout
I have no console error no syntax error in my IDE, and my path /sign-in work but for some reason the SignOutOption I've used didn't change my url on click.
Here is a snippet of my code where I've used the option:
<SignedIn>
          <SignOutButton signOutOptions={{ redirectUrl: "/sign-in" }}>
            <div className="flex cursor-pointer gap-4 p-4">
              <Image
                src="/assets/logout.svg"
                alt="logout"
                width={24}
                height={24}
              />
              <p className="text-light-2 max-lg:hidden">Logout</p>
            </div>
          </SignOutButton>
        </SignedIn>

I'm new to clerk and I didn't find example of signOutOptions in the documentation so I apologize if you have find one.
Here is my full code:
"use client";
import { sidebarLinks } from "@/constants";
import { SignOutButton, SignedIn } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function LeftSidebar() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <section className="custom-scrollbar leftsidebar">
      <div className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-col gap6 px-6">
        {sidebarLinks.map((link) => {
          const isActive =
            (pathname.includes(link.route) && link.route.length > 1) ||
            pathname === link.route;
          return (
            <Link
              href={link.route}
              key={link.label}
              className={`leftsidebar_link ${isActive && "bg-primary-500"}`}
            >
              <Image
                src={link.imgURL}
                alt={link.label}
                width={24}
                height={24}
              />
              <p className="text-light-1 max-lg:hidden">{link.label}</p>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="mt-10 px-6">
        <SignedIn>
          <SignOutButton signOutOptions={{ redirectUrl: "/sign-in" }}>
            <div className="flex cursor-pointer gap-4 p-4">
              <Image
                src="/assets/logout.svg"
                alt="logout"
                width={24}
                height={24}
              />
              <p className="text-light-2 max-lg:hidden">Logout</p>
            </div>
          </SignOutButton>
        </SignedIn>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

I'm trying to redirect my user to /sign-in when they logout

The LeftSideBar in my project is quite the same. I am facing a similar issue here. When user (try to) log out, they are not actually logging out.
here are the code snippets that might be helpful -
const { signOut } = useClerk();

const handleLogout = async () => {
        await signOut();
        router.push('/sign-in'); // Redirect to sign-in page after logout
    };


            <SignedIn>
                    <div className="flex cursor-pointer" onClick={handleLogout}>
                        <Image
                            src="/assets/logout.svg"
                            alt="logout"
                            width={24}
                            height={24}
                        />

                        <p className="text-light-2 max-lg:hidden px-4" >
                            Logout
                        </p>
                    </div>
            </SignedIn>

Have you resolved the issue? Tell me about it.

<SignOutButton redirectUrl= "/sign-in">
Try this, use redirectUrl directly instead of signOutOptions. This worked for me.

Yeah totaly worked thank's you man !

If you are using new version of clerk, they moved this to the ClerkProvider so you can define there the redirect url afterSignedOut.
